# What are some examples of Java command line arguments?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I'm a thorough novice. Could someone give me some examples of Java command line arguments and explain them? I have exhausted Google and I am still confused about exactly what they are.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+command+line+arguments&oq=java+command+line+arguments&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60j0l2.3782j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: [Java Tutorials: Command-Line Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Comment: a, foo, 123, hello. Your imagination is the limit.

Comment: When you say arguments, do you mean command line switches for the JRE itself?

Comment: This question barely scrapes the criteria for off-topic. A simple edit could have solved this rather than putting it on hold. It's this kind of unhelpful moderation that puts off new users.

Answer (score 3):

[Command line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) are just the arguments parsed into the `main(String[] args)` method of a program, usually via the command prompt (or whichever console your operating system happens to use).

So a random example might be;

```
public class Example{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("The Command line arguments entered were:");
        for(String s : args){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

All this does is take the arguements that are parsed into the program when you run it, and prints them to the console. So, for example, if we gave the program the following arguments

```
C:\exampledirectory> java Example derp unicorns 1 and 6
```

Then the output will be;

```
The Command line arguments entered were:
derp
unicorns
1
and
6
```

Each one of those words typed into CMD after the required text for running the class is a command line argument. They are parsed into the main method in the `String` array declared as the method argument `args`. All the code in the method body is doing is looping through the array and printing each value, ie each command line argument.

I hope this helps.